# Parse all whitespace and grammar

Tags: python, regex, string, file, parsing

I want to create a Python parser for parsing white space and grammar in a file. What I want to do is read a file, and place every single whitespace, punctuation, and word into its own element in a list. The following I have so far for splitting up whitespace:

```
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
  words = re.split("(\s+)", f.read())
```

with `words` holds a list of the file contents with each white space as its own element. However, I'm having trouble parsing the punctuation as a list element can contain items like `"Hello"` with the quotation marks in the element. Rather, I'd like it so that it'd look like so:

```
list = ['"', 'Hello', '"', '@', 'World']
```

as opposed to:

```
list = ['"Hello"', '@World']
```

If anyone could help me out, that would be great!

Comment: `\s` means whitespace. if you want to split on other things, you'll have to add that to the split regex. e.g. `[\s"'@]`

Comment: Well, I want to include the "'@ all as elements if possible. @MarcB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought edi_allen had it, but then saw that the white space didn't make it into the list using findall.

```
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
  words = re.split('(["\'@&,;:\(\)\s+\*\?\.]|\w+)', f.read())

#because each list element is separated from the next by an empty string:
while '' in words:
    words.remove('')    
print (words)
```

Given a text file with the following content:

> BRIAN: What will they do to me?
>
> BEN: Oh, you'll probably get away with crucifixion.
>
> BRIAN: Crucifixion?!
>
> BEN: Yeah, first offence.

The returned list is:

```
>>>  ['BRIAN', ':', ' ', 'What', ' ', 'will', ' ', 'they', ' ', 
'do', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'me', '?', '\n', 'BEN', ':', ' ', 'Oh', ',', ' ',
'you', "'", 'll', ' ', 'probably', ' ', 'get', ' ', 'away', ' ',
'with', ' ', 'crucifixion', '.', '\n', 'BRIAN', ':', ' ',
'Crucifixion', '?', '!', '\n', 'BEN', ':', ' ', 'Yeah', ',', ' ',
'first', ' ', 'offence', '.', ' ', '\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting you can use **re.findall** for this.

```
import re

string = '"hello" @world'
L = re.findall(r'(\w+|[@"])', string)
print(L)
#['"', 'hello', '"', '@', 'world']
```